# Is there a way to reset all values in a function that received many inputs?

Tags: python, function, reset

I have this function that makes people book a parking ticket in python.

The function is not important. But it takes input like any other function and outputs these values according to the calculations and conditions given.  But is there a way to reset all values and parameters inside the function after use, so if I use it again in the same run, all data will be the same as when I would run it again?

Comment: The function is too long to put here and I think it is not relevant to the question. But if you ask for it, I can give it to you

Comment: running it again should automatically work, can you edit your answer with the output if you run it several times in the same script?

Comment: Can you give a short, runnable example?  Is it the arguments to the function you want to retain?  Is there data inside the function you want to retain?  Does the function have side effects (modifies data that is external to the function)?

Comment: it's impossible to answer this without having a little bit more of context, what needs to be reset?

Comment: "But is there a way to reset all values and parameters inside the function after use" all parameters and other local variables are discarded after the function terminates, and are created again when you run the function again. So it really isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: I think some of the variables are objects which are mutated, I don't see how else there would be a problem

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are local to the function, then they will be re-initialized just as they were when the function was run for the first time. If the values are not local to the function (i.e they are declared outside of the function), then you will need to add some code to the beginning of the function to set them to values that will allow the function to work as expected